# Mapping from two different data sources

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React functional component with the following JSX:

```
import React from "react";

const Parent = () => {
  const arr1 = ["123", "456"];
  const arr2 = ["abc", "def"];

  return (
    <div>
      {arr1.map((item) => {
        return <div>{item}</div>;
      })}
      {arr2.map((item) => {
        return <div>{item}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

What I need this component to render is:

```
"123"
"abc"
"456"
"def"
```

Instead, it returns:

```
"123"
"456"
"abc"
"def"
```

I tried to get the result with a for loop, but for some reason it doesn't get triggered when the functional component is loaded, so I'm looking for a solution that involves `.map()`. Is there a way to get the needed result with `.map()`?

**Note:** the lengths of arrays are always equal, hence the accepted answer.

Comment: you messed up, you have to change the order in teh arrays itself. so what you is change the values. you are getting the correct values as per you code

Comment: The values I get are not what I need. I believe I specified in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both array have the same length:

```
<div>
  {arr1.map((item, index) => (<>
    <div>{item}</div>
    <div>{arr2[index]}</div>
   </>);
  )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return (
  <div>
    {arr1.map((value, index) => {
       return <> <div>{value}</div> <div>{arr2[index]}</div> </>
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

what you want to do is loop through both arrays at the same time, and store each value of both into a new array, something like the below.

I only added those length checks in case the arrays dont have the same size.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const arr1 = ["123", "456"];
  const arr2 = ["abc", "def"];

  let arr3 = [];

  if(arr1.length == arr2.length){
      for(let i =0;i<arr1.length;i++){
        arr3.push(arr1[i]);
        arr3.push(arr2[i]);    
      }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {arr3.map((item) => {
        return <div>{item}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Some Resources:

- [Reacts Loops](https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-loop/)
- [Beginner Guides to Loops](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/beginners-guide-loops-in-react-jsx)